# Ant run target on netbeans file save

Tags: php, netbeans, ant

I am having a Netbeans PHP Project from Remote Sources and I'd like to run an ant target from build.xml (which just echoes `test` for now) every a file in the project gets saved.

I have googled it, but have no tfound a good result. How would it be possible to do this?

I got this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="warframemarketplace" basedir="." default="test">
    <target name="test">
        <echo>Test</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

But now I need to figure out how to run it on save.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create your own plugin.

Use

- [**ActionUtils** to execute the ant task](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-apache-tools-ant-module/org/apache/tools/ant/module/api/support/ActionUtils.html#runTarget%28org.openide.filesystems.FileObject,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.util.Properties%29)
- [**OnSaveTask** to register it as a save action](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-editor-lib2/org/netbeans/spi/editor/document/OnSaveTask.Factory.html)